# JqGrid: Horizontal Delimiter in Add/Edit Form

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jqgrid

In the jqGrid Add/Edit form screens I would like to insert a horizontal delimiter to "section off" certain input boxes. In the examples on the jqGrid Wiki [page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing) it displays the horizontal bar between each input box but never explains how to print the bar to the form.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: it's not clear what you mean under "horizontal delimiter" or " horizontal bar between each input box". The Add/Edit form includes the table with two columns. The first column contains the name of editable column and the second column contains edit control. If you don't specified any [edittype](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#edittype) then jqGrid uses `<input type="text">`. So what is your problem? Which additional separators or delimiter you want to insert in the Add/Edit form?